preseed on ubuntu 24.04 fail to manuel install because of unknown kernel command
i try to install ubuntu 24.04 with preseed.  while boot i set the grub command to:
linux /casper/vmlinuz auto preseed/url=http://10.6.48.5:8000/preseed.cfg

but the computer set to manuel installation.  in /var/log/syslog i find the messages:

2024-12-16T08:18:30.360425+00:00 ubuntu kernel: Kernel command line:
BOOT_IMAGE=/casper/vmlinuz auto
preseed/url=http://10.6.48.5:8000/preseed.cfg
2024-12-16T08:18:30.360426+00:00 ubuntu kernel: Unknown kernel command
line parameters "auto BOOT_IMAGE=/casper/vmlinuz
preseed/url=http://10.6.48.5:8000/preseed.cfg", will be passed to user
space.

i tried using automatic-ubiquity instead or with auto, but, the same problem.
UPDATE:
following Saxtheowl's note, i try cloud-init.  the grub line:
linux /casper/vmlinuz autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=http://10.0.0.1/autoinstall/

the same problem and the log:

2024-12-17T11:49:04.819867+00:00 ubuntu kernel: Kernel command line:
BOOT_IMAGE=/casper/vmlinuz autoinstall ds=nocloud-net
2024-12-17T11:49:04.819869+00:00 ubuntu kernel: Unknown kernel command
line parameters "autoinstall BOOT_IMAGE=/casper/vmlinuz
ds=nocloud-net", will be passed to user space.


it is no longer supported in Ubuntu’s newer installers, look into the new autoinstall parameter and a user-data configuration rather than auto preseed/url
